# Is it possible to get DISTINCT rows from RETURNING clause?

Tags: postgresql, sql-returning

We're using PostgreSQL v8.2.3.

Is it possible to get DISTINCT rows from an UPDATE statement using *RETURNING*
clause?

*MYTABLE* columns are:

1. APRIMARYKEYCOLUMN
2. ABOOLEANCOLUMN
3. EMAIL
4. COLUMN1
5. COLUMN2
6. COLUMN3

UPDATE using RETURNING clause query:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET ABOOLEANCOLUMN = true FROM MYTEMPTABLE WHERE EMAIL =
MYTEMPTABLE.EMAIL RETURNING EMAIL, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3;
```

Here in this case, I expect to return distinct rows from these columns:
EMAIL, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3.

I even tried out some ways of getting distinct rows, but it doesn't work.
Though I can still solve this at application layer, I'm trying to find
whether this could be solved/controlled at query-level.  Any different
ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. RETURNING is great but it's not the same as a normal SELECT statement. RETURNING is record based, not set based. DISTINCT works on a set.

Comment: @Frank: No other possible way to get DISTINCT rows out from this record-based?

Comment: You could wrap the update in a stored procedure and let this procedure handle the distinctnes. But what problem do you have when you can't use distinct? RETURNING tells you which records have been updated.

Comment: @Frank: Based on the DISTINCT row from here, I've some application logic attached to this at the next level. Nothing else.

Comment: Fix it in your application, keep the logic together. RETURNING can't do it for you, too bad.

Comment: @Frank: This is just for my understanding.  What exactly is the difference between *record-based* and *set-based*?

Comment: A set can have a MIN or MAX value over many records, a single record has only it's own value and can't interact with other records. RETURNING can't tell you anything about a set of records (MIN, MAX, DISTINCT), it can only return the records.

Answer (score 17):

This is an old question but since it came up as the first answer in a search and that answer is out of date I'm sharing.

Using common table expressions (CTEs) which has been available since PG version 8.4 you can update/delete and get a distinct result.

```
WITH updater AS
(
  UPDATE MYTABLE SET ABOOLEANCOLUMN = true FROM MYTEMPTABLE WHERE EMAIL = MYTEMPTABLE.EMAIL RETURNING EMAIL, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
)
SELECT DISTINCT EMAIL, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM updater;
```